# Installation of IIS and MSMQ is taking too much time in wix setup

Tags: iis, installation, wix, msmq

We are using wix toolset to build a setup. I has more than 15 thousand files to install. At the beginning, it should install IIS and MSMQ windows features. Only this part of the installation is taking more than one hour to finish. If I turn off installation of windows features, the setup is finishing after no more than 15 minutes. How to solve the problem? How to minimize the time for the installation of those windows features?

**EDITED:**
All I run via cmd.exe for MSMQ is:

```
/Online /enable-feature /all /featurename:MSMQ-Server /featurename:MSMQ-Triggers 
/featurename:MSMQ-ADIntegration /featurename:MSMQ-HTTP /featurename:MSMQ-Multicast
```

For IIS is:

```
/online /enable-feature /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole 
/all /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET 
/All /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility 
/FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions 
/FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing 
/FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging 
/FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering
```

Comment: That's impossible to minimize. It is Windows (or its CBS) that decides how long to install, not you or anyone else.

Comment: Not sure what the overall motivation is here, but to speed up debugging and testing I would either split the setups in two (so the main setup itself is faster to build and install) and install the prerequisites with the first one, or build a debug version of the setup containing no prerequisites at all in order for it to build and install faster that way. I guess this is what you already do? MSI itself is quite slow to install so many files, and that has to do with [all the overhead involved in its operation](https://serverfault.com/a/594661/20599). What are the specs of this computer?

Comment: Some people use legacy installers to install IIS-setups because of MSIs poor performance with lots of small files. Not recommended, but possible. I never thought it would take that long to install IIS and MSMQ? Do they require a lot of Windows update after installation? What anti virus is on the box?

Comment: @LexLi I have to say that sometimes, it installs in 5 minutes, sometimes in 55 minutes... But what factors do effect on this? Decision of Windows (or its CBS) should also be logical and should depend on something.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yes, IIS and MSMQ are prerequisites. I need to say that installation of all files with some custom actions are not taking more than 15 minutes. The main stuck is on the installation of windows features. 
After installing MSMQ or IIS or any other windows feature, Windows also will be updated? I did not know that. It means, setup installs MSMQ in 5 minutes and then, Windows updates itself for 45-50 minutes? Am I right? That's interesting

Comment: I don't think that Windows Updates happen automatically, but you should run Windows Updates to ensure all components are updated - or you could have security issues on the box. I don't know if Windows 10 does this now itself automatically. You could check the system's event log? What spec is this machine in terms of hardware?

Comment: No, from security side - there is no problem (no antivirus soft). Internet speed is fast without any connection errors. Let me check event log next time when I run. In terms of hardware, memory 8GB, processor Intel Xeon CPU 2.00GHz, 100 GB HDD, OS - Windows Server 2016 x64

Comment: Hmmm, that hardware looks quite old. That is a very small disk for example? Almost virtual machine size? Is this a physical box or a virtual? (just to be sure). Tell you what, I would ask on [serverfault.com](https://www.serverfault.com) - system administrators - how long the installation of IIS and MSMQ should take, and if there are any tricks. Also, is that an SSD disk? How much free space does it have? There is also [superuser.com](https://www.superuser.com) (advanced computer users).

Answer (score 0):

For speeding up the IIS/MSMQ phase the only thing you can really do is eliminate the dependency on IIS and MSMQ.   This would be an application rewrite though.

For making the MSI portion faster there are tricks you can do like multiple files per component and set some properties to enable fast installation and disable rollback.  I doubt it would save that much time though.

Comment: I guess this is impossible to eleminate the dependency. We have a bunch of websites and application pools.

Comment: As for general speeding up - yes, we have multiple files per component. There is no problem with the general speed of installation

Comment: Looking at those hardware specs, I am wondering if that is a virtual? If so, I suppose it could be continually adjusting its disk size during installation? That could be very slow? Either way that is not a lot of disk space for such a large installation.